# Long lines are printed with extra white spaces in between on Zebra printer (ZPL)

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm using Zebra Designer 2 to create some labels and when I have a long label (more than 30 characters) the printer puts an extra space between every two words. When I use the print preview feature of the software, the label looks good, but the real printed label is broken. Here is a sample of the printing result:

[image]

This is the ZPL code generated by Zebra Designer:

```
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR5,5~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^LS0
^FT99,269^A0N,23,24^FH\^FDTEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO^FS
^FT99,205^A0N,25,24^FH\^FDTEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO^FS
^FT92,141^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDTEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO^FS
^FT88,357^A@N,23,22,TT0003M_^FH\^CI17^F8^FDTEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO^FS^CI0
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

The printer is a ZP550 (DHL), 200 dpi and the media is 10cm x 20cm (non continuous).

Comment: Please post your code :)

Answer (score 2):

One issue you need to be wary of is wrapping of text, by default you will have a paper size of Letter or A4 which will wrap the text automatically after approximately 80 characters. If you need to support a full 132 column width then you need to change the paper size in the printing preferences to "US Std Fanfold" and leave the orientation on portrait which is wide paper in this case.

I set it to US Std Fanfold and the issue went away